# Difficulties setting up GitLab CI in 8.8.5 from scratch

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have difficulties to get GitLab CI (version 8.8.5) running with separate nginx (nginx/1.10.0, Ubuntu 14.04) configuration. My GitLab instance is running well and all works fine. What is the correct path to the gitlab-ci socket which I can refer in my nginx configuration file? I did not find anything in the gitlab directory.

Here is what I set up *(I replaced my real domain with example.com)*:

GitLab settings `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```sh
external_url 'http://git.example.com'
ci_external_url 'https://ci.example.com'
gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'Europe/Berlin'
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
ci_nginx['enable'] = false
```

GitLab nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab`:

```sh
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen *:443;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.example.com/privkey.pem;

  server_name git.example.com;

  server_tokens off;

  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/git.example.com/access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/git.example.com/error.log;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name git.example.com;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

GitLab CI nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab-ci`:

```sh
upstream gitlab_ci {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen *:443;

  server_name ci.example.com;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.example.com/privkey.pem;

  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-ci/public;

  client_max_body_size 250m;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/ci.example.com/access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/ci.example.com/error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab_ci;
  }

  location @gitlab_ci {
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab_ci;
  }

}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name ci.example.com;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The nginx error log will print the following:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/ci.example.com/error.log 

2016/06/17 11:07:31 [crit] 6192#0: *30 connect() to unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/sockets/gitlab.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: ci.example.com, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/sockets/gitlab.socket:/robots.txt", host: "XX.XX.XX.XX"
```

When checking the GitLab directory I do not found any socket which I can refer in my configuration:

```sh
/var/opt/gitlab # ls -lF *
-rw------- 1 root         root         38 Jan 19 14:57 bootstrapped

git-data:
drwxrws--- 11 git git 4096 Feb 24 16:26 repositories/

gitlab-ci:
drwx------ 2 git root 4096 Jan 19 14:56 builds/

gitlab-rails:
drwx------ 2 git  root       4096 Jun 17 11:00 etc/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root          8 Jun 15 16:42 REVISION
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         58 Mar 22 16:41 RUBY_VERSION
drwxr-x--x 5 git  gitlab-www 4096 Jan 19 14:56 shared/
drwxr-x--- 2 git  gitlab-www 4096 Jun 15 16:42 sockets/
drwx------ 3 git  root       4096 Jan 19 16:19 tmp/
drwx------ 2 git  root       4096 Jun 15 16:42 upgrade-status/
drwx------ 7 git  gitlab-www 4096 Feb  9 12:57 uploads/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root          6 Jun 15 16:42 VERSION
drwx------ 2 git  root       4096 Jan 19 14:56 working/

gitlab-shell:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1823 Jun 17 10:51 config.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  129 Jan 19 14:56 gitlab_shell_secret

gitlab-workhorse:
srwxrwxrwx 1 git  git   0 Jun 15 16:42 socket=
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40 Jun 15 16:42 VERSION

logrotate:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  425 Feb 24 22:18 logrotate.conf
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 11:00 logrotate.d/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  880 Jun 17 10:52 logrotate.status

nginx:
drwx------ 2 gitlab-www root       4096 Jan 19 14:57 client_body_temp/
drwxr-x--- 2 root       gitlab-www 4096 Jun 17 11:00 conf/
drwx------ 2 gitlab-www root       4096 Jan 19 14:57 fastcgi_temp/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root       root         21 Jan 19 14:57 logs -> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/
drwx------ 8 gitlab-www root       4096 Jan 19 15:49 proxy_temp/
drwx------ 2 gitlab-www root       4096 Jan 19 14:57 scgi_temp/
drwx------ 2 gitlab-www root       4096 Jan 19 14:57 uwsgi_temp/

postgresql:
drwx------ 14 gitlab-psql root 4096 Jun 17 11:00 data/

redis:
-rw------- 1 gitlab-redis gitlab-redis 201024 Jun 17 11:10 dump.rdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-redis root          29778 Mar  3 16:16 redis.conf
srwxrwxrwx 1 gitlab-redis gitlab-redis      0 Jun 15 16:41 redis.socket=
```

What am I missing? Is there anyone who can give me a hint how to set up my GitLab CI properly? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: From my own experience setting `ci_external_url` does absolutely nothing and the CI is already available from `http://git.example.com/ci` regardless

Comment: Unfortunately, the url `https://git.example.com/ci` redirects to my GitLab dashboard.

Comment: It redirects you to the dashboard, but the CI runner will communicate with GitLab over this URL. Registering the runner with the URL https://git.example.com/ci works with this.

Comment: Thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from version 8.0 GitLab CI is fully integrated into GitLab. This actually means that no specific CI configuration is necessary, just a general GitLab nginx file.

If your `external_url` is `http://gitlab.example.com` then your CI is already available for runners on `http://gitlab.example.com/ci`. Use this URL to register your runner for the GitLab CI.